# MySQL Synchronisation via Dropbox between different systems

Tags: mysql, dropbox, synchronization

I want to synchronize my MySQL database between my desktop, laptop and tablet. On the desktop (win 7 home basic) and the laptop (win 7 starter) there is a wamp server version 2.2 running. On the tablet I use a Palapa Web Server 2.1.1 under Android 4.2

I read the article at [Tech Blog - Abhishek Sachan](http://abhisheksachan.blogspot.com/2012/08/web-development-environment-made-easy.html) and I made already all the changes in the  httpd.conf and the my.ini files.

Also I installed a Dropbox folder with the same folders to be synchronized in it on each machine and take care that all have the same 'data'-folder with the same files for the MySQL.

So far everything works already fine and I am able to open the PhpMyAdmin on each device. I found the same database and the same tables with all the records I need. In fact it is only one small database with three tables - but I guess this does not matter.

But when I change a record on one device the Dropbox starts the synchronization. But after that the changing is not to be seen on the other devices. They are still with the old record.

Does anybody have an idea what is wrong with my idea? Thanks a lot so far 
Andreas

Comment: Try to close mysql service and open it again. Do the changes apply?

Comment: Hi Peter - many thanks for your suggestion. In between it works already. I think it was all very slow and I have been too impatient to see the result. Another problem was may be that I worked simultaneous on the other devices for testing and that causes some problem with the Dropbox. All in all I am not really satisfied with the speed and the synchronization. But at least it works. Have a nice time
Andreas!